# How can I tell if Language Fallback is in effect?

Tags: multilingual, language-fallback

In a solution with Item level language fallback enabled, how do I tell if this is in effect for the current item?  I would like to set the `html` element `lang` attribute to the language that is being displayed.

For example, if Spanish is requested and a Spanish version exists, it should be set to `lang='es'`. But if the item falls back to English, it should be set to `lang='en'`.

I tried:

```
var language = Sitecore.Context.Item.Versions.Count > 0 ?
            Sitecore.Context.Item.Language :
            Sitecore.Context.Item.GetFallbackItem().Language;
```

But this always returns the requested language, as the count appears to be greater than zero due to Language fallback.

Answer (score 1):

**Update:** Just use `IsFallback` property on the item.  Duh.  (Thanks Amish Naik!)

**The hard way:**

Use the LanguageFallbackItemSwitcher class to temporarily disable fallback:

```
Language language;
Language itemLanguage = Sitecore.Context.Item.Language;
Language fallbackLanguage = Sitecore.Context.Item.GetFallbackItem().Language;
using (new LanguageFallbackItemSwitcher(false))
{
    language = Sitecore.Context.Item.Versions.Count > 0 ? itemLanguage: fallbackLanguage; 
}
```